# How to use global phpunit instaed of the redirection by composer?

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit, composer-php

I would like to use my global phpunit in version 4.8.27 installed by : yum install phpunit.

When I'm in my symfony2 project, I have tried to run my test with phpunit but I got this error :

```
==== Redirecting to composer installed version in vendor/phpunit ====

PHP Fatal error:  Class 'PHPUnit_Util_ErrorHandler' not found in /project/vendor/my/core-bundle/src/CoreBundle/Tests/Functional/Controller/ControllerBaseTestCase.php on line 1181

PHPUnit 4.8.28 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
THE ERROR HANDLER HAS CHANGED!
```

We can see the difference 4.8.27 and 4.8.28.
But I want to use global without redirection.

Can you help me to deal with it ?

Comment: that's just mean that you're using composer's autoloader.

Comment: How did you try to run your tests with the system PHPUnit? What was the exact command?

Comment: Im using : phpunit -c phpunit.functional.xml.dist
If I remove this vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit , it's work, but it's a bad solution :/

Comment: @TanguyBernard, your system PHPUnit is probably at `/usr/bin/phpunit`. Try running `/usr/bin/phpunit -c phpunit.functional.xml.dist`. (If your system PHPUnit is elsewhere you'll have to adjust accordingly. Try `type -a phpunit` to see all the options.)

Comment: From where are you running this command?

Comment: @Chris /usr/bin/phpunit -c phpunit.functional.xml.dist -> same redirection unfortunately.

Comment: @DerStoffel Im running from my root project (src,app, vendor, phpunit.functional.xml.dist...)